# Como chamar arquivos CSS utilizando Kohana PHP 3.3

Tags: php, css, kohana

Sou iniciante no `Kohana Framework` e gostaria de saber como faço para chamar um arquivo CSS.

Comment: Não é claro o que você está perguntando? É clarissimo o que o AP está perguntando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar  **URL::base:**

```
<?php echo URL::base(); ?>
```

Exemplo: `<link src="<?=url::base()?>assets/css/layout.css" />`